# Rails - Extract HTTP Verb From Named Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way in Rails to extract the HTTP verb(s) associated with a route?  For example, given a route like this:

`match 'users', to: 'users#show', via: [:get, :post]`

Can I achieve something like this?

`users_path.respond_to?(:get)` (obviously #respond_to is not the right method)

The closest I've managed to come is by doing the following, but it doesn't really seem satisfactory.

`Rails.application.routes.routes.named_routes["users"].constraints[:request_method] # => /^GET$/`

For context, I have an action that sets a cookie and then does a `redirect_to :back`, but this action is available globally across the entire site (it's in the footer). So, if a user happens to be in a flow, and one of those routes only accepts POSTs, the redirect fails because the request issued is a GET.

Comment: You can always pipe `rake routes` and parse that.

Comment: Hm, an interesting idea.  I'll have to give this a try.

Comment: @SunnyJuneja Despite your idea being clever, it doesn't seem very practical or performant.  The closest I got was `rake routes.split(/\n/).map { |r| r.split(/\s+/) }`.  SO doesn't seem to allow escaping backticks, so it should be noted that `rake routes` should be encapsulated by such because it's a shell command.

Comment: How fast does this need to be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `request` object is available to your controller. The following methods are available to determine the type of HTTP request:

```
if request.get?
  # request is a GET request
if request.post?
  # request is a POST request
```

There are similar methods for other HTTP request verbs, including PUT and DELETE.

**UPDATE**:

Per the update to the question, the following code can be implemented within your controller to yield the constrained verbs on any named route as a pipe-delimited string:

```
Rails.application.routes.named_routes["users"].verb
#=> "GET|POST"
```

Accordingly, you can split the string to retrieve an array of each of the HTTP methods specified in the route's `constraints`:

```
methods_string = Rails.application.routes.named_routes["users"].verb
#=> "GET|POST"

methods_array = methods_string.split('|')
#=> ["GET", "POST"]

methods_array[0]
#=> "GET"
methods_array[1]
#=> "POST"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this isn't quite what I'm looking for.  I'm looking to retrieve the HTTP verb for arbitrary routes, not just the one associated with the current request.

Comment: Hmm... I'm curious as to how something like that would be invoked. Would this be something in the controller? In the view? Knowing something about the use-case might be helpful, also.

Comment: I've edited the original question to provide additional context.  This would be something needed at the controller level.

Comment: `Rails.application.routes.named_routes["users"].verb` returns a `Regexp` object rather than a string in Rails 4 (I'm pretty sure it was the same in 3.2). That just means you may not be able to simple call `#split` to get a list of verbs.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works as of Rails 3.2. @Malorn, can you verify whether you've had any luck with this?

Comment: @WizardofOgz is correct -- in Rails 4 this returns a pipe delimited `Regexp` object.  @zeantsoi In any case, this looks like it will provide what I need.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

for someone looking with it in future you can use

```
env["REQUEST_METHOD"]
```

to get HTTP verb of specific action